# Web cookie uniqueness between two clients

Tags: node.js, cookies

I'm writing a cookies module for practice and am wondering if cookies names and values need to be unique between clients. In other words if client A has a response sent cookie that looks like `res.append('Set-Cookie', 'flavor=mint')` can client B have the same cookie or does the cookie name and value need to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the same cookie value on as many clients as you like.

You can imagine a simple example e-commerce site that maybe stored the id of the contents of their customer's shopping carts as cookies to ensure they are in the cart upon their return to the site. If you put an item in your shopping cart on this site while shopping in your browser, and I put the exact same item in my shopping cart on my browser, the cookie values would need to be the same.